# How do I install composer dependencies in Eclipse PDT?

Tags: php, eclipse, composer-php, eclipse-pdt

I recently installed [Eclipse PDT](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/php-development-tools) and I am having trouble installing composer dependencies. This is the button to install dependencies:

[image: screenshot install dependencies]

When I click the button, the console view appears and displays the (very) uninformative text: "Could not open input file: Files". I used the native terminal to manually run `composer update`, but I want to be able to use the Eclipse integration.

How can I make the composer integration work so I can install my dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to "Window" > "Preferences" expand the "PHP" > Tools section > and select "Composer". And check the path to the composer.phar file or just composer if it is in your PATH , you can also check the path to the PHP executable. After applying test the dependency installation again.[image]

If you don't have the package installed, access help > install new software... select all available sites and search for php packages, select and install. Then try the procedure above. [image]

Comment: Its "Window" > "Preferences" > "PHP" >"Tools" > "Composer", but it worked! Thank you :)

Comment: I changed and included images to make it easier to understand. Thanks for the feedback